# Submit a form after event.preventDefault (event.preventDefault behavior)

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I made a register page and want it does some validation before submission. So, I put `event.preventDefault` in my handleSubmit function. `event.preventDefault` is to prevent the default function, so if the form is blank, then it wont submit. But, after I fill all blanks, it can submit. My question is `event.preventDefault` still in the handleSubmit function after blanks filled, why can the form be submitted? Or, if user fills all blanks, the `event.preventDefault` will be disabled?

Thanks!

```js
export default function RegisterPage() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    userName: "",
    nickName: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [apiResError, setApiResError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setApiResError("");
    e.preventDefault();
    registerAccount(values.userName, values.nickName, values.password).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    setErrors({ ...errors, [name]: "" });
  };

  return (
    <RegisterPageContainer>
      <RegisterPageTitle>Register</RegisterPageTitle>
      {apiResError && <div>{apiResError}</div>}
      <RegisterForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <InputWrapper>
          <UserNameInput
            name="userName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.userName}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
          />
        </InputWrapper>
        {errors.userName && <div>{errors.userName}</div>}
        <InputWrapper>
          <NickNameInput
            name="nickName"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Nickname"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.nickName}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
          />
        </InputWrapper>
        {errors.nickName && <div>{errors.nickName}</div>}
        <InputWrapper>
          <PasswordInput
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.password}
            onFocus={handleFocus}
          />
        </InputWrapper>
        {errors.password && <div>{errors.password}</div>}
        <SubmitBtn>Create An Account</SubmitBtn>
      </RegisterForm>
    </RegisterPageContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` is to prevent the form from making an http call. If you don't use that in a form submission, the page will refresh every time you submit a form.

It really has nothing to do with blocking submission when the values are empty or anything. You have to program validation logic yourself.

Your `registerAccount` function will fire every time you hit submit. `e.preventDefault()` won't block it.